# Counting and solving bijection

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the problem:

- Please count how many functions $f : D → \{0, 1 \}$ can be defined if the domain D is a finite set with the cardinality $|D| = n$.
- Is there a bijection between the set of all such functions and the powerset $\mathcal{P}(D)$?

For the first question would the answer just be $|D|=2$?

I was hoping someone can give me a hint for the second question because I am not sure how to go about solving it.

Comment: Do you really mean $D\to 0$? Or is it $D\to\{0,1\}$? Or in your definition, are partly defined "functions" allowed?

Comment: @AndréNicolas the question is as above

Comment: They already said $\lvert D \rvert = n$ so $\lvert D \rvert = 2$ can't be right.

Comment: If $A$ is a subset of $D$, define $f_A:D\to \{0,1\}$ by $f_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $f_A(x)=0$ if $x\not\in A$. The mapping $\varphi$ that maps $A$ to $f_A$ is a bijection from the power set of $D$ to the set of all functions from $D$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Note that we do not need to mention the "natural" bijection given above. There are $2^n$ functions, and the power set has $2^n$ elements, so sure, there is a bijection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^{|D|}$ such functions. Example, let $D=\{a,b,c\}\,$, so $|D|=3\,$, but there will be 8 functions from $D$ to $\{0,1\}\,$, i.e.

$\\f_1=\{(a,0),(b,0),(c,0)\}\, ,
f_2=\{(a,1),(b,0),(c,0)\}\,,
f_3=\{(a,0),(b,1),(c,0)\}\,,\\ 
f_4=\{(a,0),(b,0),(c,1)\}\,,
...,\,f_8=\{(a,1),(b,1),(c,1)\}\,.$

And the bijection between $D \rightarrow \{ 0,1\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ would be the obvious one: between the elements of  $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and their characteristic functions in $D \rightarrow \{ 0,1\} \,$. That is, from the example above, $f_1$ maps to $\emptyset \,$, $f_2$ maps to $\{a\}$, and $f_8$ maps to $\{a,b,c\}=D \,$. You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks. so here we said $|D|=3$ why can't I say $|D|=2$ and say $f1={(a,0),(b,0)}$,$f2={(a,1),(b,0)}$,$f3={(a,0),(b,1)}$,$f4={(a,1),(b,1)}$?

Comment: No, that's also fine. Similarly for all $n$ sizes of $D$. Above is just an example, to give you the idea how it looks in general. So for $|D|=2$ the number of functions is $4$ (as you correctly noticed), for $|D|=3$ the number of functions id $8$ (my example),..., and in general for $|D|=n$ the number of functions $D \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is $2^n\,$.

Comment: Ok so the answer is $4$ because $n=2$

Comment: The special case, when $|D|=2\,$, i.e. $n=2\,$ is 4, but that's not *the* answer. The question asks for $D$ of any size $n\,$. Don't confuse reading $D \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ as $D = \{0,1\}$, and so confusingly take $|D|=2\,$. $\{0,1\}$ is the stipulated range (co-domain) of all the functions from the domain $D$ that you're supposed to count.

Comment: ok so if we do not know what $D$ is then we can say the answer for part one is $2^{|D|}$

Answer (score 2):

No, let $D=\{a,b,c\}$, so $n=3$.  How many choices do you have for $f(a)$?  How many for $f(b)?$  How many functions does that make overall?  If you list the functions it may help with the answer for 2.

Comment: so would $n=4$?

Comment: No, you defined $n=|D|$, so it is $3$ here.  There is one more choice to make for the function.

Comment: I would have thought that there are $2^{|D|}$ such functions, i.e. $f_1=\{(a,0),(b,0),(c,0) \} \,$, $f_2=\{(a,1),(b,0),(c,0) \} \,$, $f_3=\{(a,0),(b,1),(c,0) \} \,$, $f_3=\{(a,0),(b,0),(c,1) \} \,$, $f_4=\{(a,1),(b,1),(c,0) \} \,$,... 8 in total here.

Comment: @prime4567:  You are correct. That is where I was hoping to get OP to.  $n$ is not the number of functions, it is the number of elements of $D$.

Comment: And the bijection between $D \rightarrow \{ 0,1\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ would be the obvious one: between the elements of  $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and their characteristic functions in $D \rightarrow \{ 0,1\} \,$.

Comment: I was thinking of $2^{|D|}$ that is why  I said $4$

Comment: for the second part it would just be (∅,{0},{1},{0,1}) right?

Comment: See my answer, below.

Comment: @Csci319: as I said $|D|=3,$ so $2^{|D|}=2^3=8$. prime4567 has given a listing of the eight functions.  You are not looking for subsets of $\{0,1\}$.  You have two choices for $f(a)$, two for $f(b)$, two for $f(c)$, so $2^3=8$ total.  Much more generally, the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$.  *You need to understand this*.  The logic is the multiplication principle for choices.